# Handling button mdl-js styling with dynamic innerHTML change

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design-lite

Changing `<button>` innerHTML seems to deactivate mdl-js-ripple-effect. 
Use the method [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558720/dynamically-add-items-to-an-mdl-menu) to dynamically build a new element as the workaround or report this as a bug?

```
<body>
    <button id="myButton" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">OLD VALUE
    </button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML = "new value";

});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVvMOE

Tried the `componentHandler.upgradeElement(button)` on the existing element after setting new html, but as mentioned in the docs it's only good for new ones. Trying to reuse existing elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I when the component is parsed and upgraded by the MDL script, a lot of extra attributes are added to the outer node, and extra HTML added inside. That means both that setting the `innerHTML` will remove some of the necessary markup inside and that the `upgradeElement` will fail because of the markup that was added to the outer node.

You should try de-upgrading the button with `componentHandler.downgradeElements` first, then set the innerHTML, then call `componentHandler.upgradeElement`.

Some untested sample code:

```
function setText(element,newtext){
    componentHandler.downgradeElements(element);
    element.innerHTML=newtext;
    componentHandler.upgradeElement(element);
}
setText(document.getElementById('myButton'),'new value');
```

Comment: drown-grading it twice, before setting innerHTML, seems to work for some reason. now curious why the same `componentHandler.downgradeElements(element);` statement needs repeated 2 times. [new version](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEoXPz)

Comment: seems like the need to repeat the downgrade twice went away with v1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue. I'm trying to add some card via innerHtml into the page. The card contains a radio button using the class mdl-radio.

Everything seems to work fine, but the radio button doesn't load the style. I'm seeing a simple radio button not the styled one. If I add the card to the page from the beggining the radio button looks OK, as expected.

Any comment is welcome, I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
     main.innerHTML =  '<!-- CARD PREGUNTA-->\
  <div class="demo-cards mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;" id="pregunta_card">\
  <div class="demo-updates mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">\
  <!-- Contenido -->\
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600">\
  <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text" id="pregunta_card_title"></h2>\
  <br>\
  <br>\
  <!-- Radio Button 1 -->\
  <label id="opt1" class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option1">\
  <input type="radio" id="option1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options"/>\
  <!-- intitial state checked using attribute checked  -->\
  <span class="mdl-radio__label" id="option1_value"></span>\
  </label>\
  </div>\
  </div>'
```