# How to Edit the text of a MDL Button with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, material-design-lite

I am currently working on a project which uses [MDL Lite](https://getmdl.io/) and is basically a controller for a device I am building. The webpage has buttons, all defined as standard MDL Buttons with Ripple.

I need to make the button's text change when something happens. The problem is, however, when every is use JQuery to change the `html` of the button (specifically the text displayed), the ripple effect vanishes.

After some research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762689/handling-button-mdl-js-styling-with-dynamic-innerhtml-change). The solution does work but I have exactly 29 buttons, and downgrading then upgrading them each causes a lot of lag.

Is there any other way to fix this problem which doesn't cause lag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the real-time HTML updates in Chrome, I noticed the `mdl-buttom` only adds a span for the ripple effect, with the text right before it.

A simple fast workaround is change the button's text by [modifying the html before the child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809/how-can-i-change-an-elements-text-without-changing-its-child-elements).